# Integration $I_n=\int _0^{\pi }\sin^{2n}\theta d\theta $

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

If $I_n=\int _0^{\pi }\sin^{2n}\theta \:d\theta $, show that
$I_n=\frac{\left(2n-1\right)}{2n}I_{n-1}$, and hence $I_n=\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{\left(2^nn!\right)2}\pi $

Hence calculate $\int _0^{\pi }\:\sin^4t\cos^6t\:dt$

I knew how to prove that $I_n=\frac{\left(2n-1\right)}{2n}I_{n-1}$, but I am not very good at English, what does it mean Hence $I_n=\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{\left(2^nn!\right)2}\pi $ do we need to prove this part as well or is it just a hint to use? and for the other calculation to find $\int _0^{\pi }\:\sin^4t\cos^6t\:dt$ is there something in the first part that I can do to help me solve this question because otherwise it becomes very long and it's part of the question.

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint for the second part:**

$$\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$$
so
$$\cos^4(x)=(1-\sin^2(x))^2=1-2\sin^2(x)+\sin^4(x)$$
and so
$$\int \sin^6(x)\cos^4(x)dx=\int \sin^6(x)(1-2\sin^2(x)+\sin^4(x))dx$$
$$=\int (\sin^6(x)-2\sin^8(x)+\sin^{10}(x))dx$$
$$=\int \sin^6(x) dx -\int2\sin^8(x)dx+\int\sin^{10}(x)dx$$
$$=\int \sin^{2(3)}(x) dx -\int2\sin^{2(4)}(x)dx+\int\sin^{2(5)}(x)dx$$

Comment: Thank you but I figured out that much so far. My question is, is there anything on the first part of the question to make the rest of the question shorter, because like this it will be very long to solve. Thank you for your help again.

Comment: I think that all you can do here is use $$I_n=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2 \theta} d \theta = \frac{2n!}{(2^nn!)2} \pi$$ to solve for the other integral given. I don't know how to prove the shortcut, though.

Comment: Thank you very much, that will do it I know how to solve it now, Thank you very much again.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative way.

$$I=\int \sin^{6}(x) dx -\int2\sin^{8}(x)dx+\int\sin^{10}(x)dx$$

Substitution

$\frac{x}{2}=t \rightarrow dx=2dt$

Integral becomes (I  am sort of manipulating it to fit Wallis' theorem)

$$I=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{6}(2t) dt -4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{8}(2t)dt+2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{10}(2t)dt$$

$$I=2(\frac{1}{2}.\frac{3}{4}.\frac{5}{6}.\frac{\pi}{2})-4(\frac{1}{2}.\frac{3}{4}.\frac{5}{6}.\frac{7}{8}.\frac{\pi}{2})+2(\frac{1}{2}.\frac{3}{4}.\frac{5}{6}.\frac{7}{8}.\frac{9}{10}.\frac{\pi}{2})$$